# use a single value from multiple text boxes into an sql query with php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have 5 textboxes in querybook.php which takes the values of bookid bookname bookauthor bookpublisher and bookedition from form in html (text boxes) to search for a book.
Bookid is the primary key of book table.
When user fills up all the fields in the html form then it is ok.
when the user fills up only a few fields or just a single field in my php page it should take up the value of that field and use it in a query to retrieve the specified books,bookname,authors,publishers or book edition. My code is given below
 which is not working as specified above for values from single field.

```
<HTML>
 <HEAD><h1 align="center">THIS IS QUERY BOOK PAGE</h1></HEAD>
 <br /> 
    <BODY>
                <FORM action="querybook.php" method="POST">
                    ENTER ANY OF THE FOLLOWING DETAILS TO SEARCH FOR A BOOK</br></br></br>
        <table>
                    <tr><td>ENTER THE BOOK ID :<td><input type=text value=bkid  name="bkid"></tr>
        <tr><td>ENTER THE NAME OF THE BOOK :<td><input type=text value=bkname autofocus="true" name="bkname"></tr>
        <tr><td>ENTER THE NAME OF THE AUTHOR :<td><input type=text value=bkauth name="bkauth"></tr>
        <tr><td>ENTER THE NAME OF THE PUBLISHER:<td><input type=text value=bkpub name="bkpub"></tr>
        <tr><td>ENTER THE NAME OF THE EDITION :<td><input type=text value=bkedn name="bkedn"></tr>
        </table>
        <BR>
                    CLICK HERE TO SUBMIT THE FORM :<input type="submit"  value="QUERY BOOK" name="submit"></br></br>
                </FORM>
                <?php
                $server="localhost";
                $username="root";
                $password="pramit";
                $link=mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die("Could not connect to database");
                mysql_select_db('test',$link);
                if(isset($_POST['submit']))    
                {
                    $bkid   = trim($_POST['bkid']);
                    $bkauth = trim($_POST['bkauth']);
                    $bkname = trim($_POST['bkname']);
                    $bkpub  = trim($_POST['bkpub']);
                    $bkedn  = trim($_POST['bkedn']);
                    if(isset($bkid) || isset($bkname) || isset($bkauth) || isset($bkpub) ||isset($bkedn))
                    {  
                        if($bkid!="" )
                        {
                            $query="select bkid,bkname,bkauth,bkpub,bkedn from books where bkid=$bkid";
                            $result=mysql_query($query);
                        }
                        if($bkname!="")
                        {
                            $query="select bkid,bkname,bkauth,bkpub,bkedn from books where bkname=$bkname";
                            $result=mysql_query($query);
                        }
                        if($bkauth!=""  )
                        {
                            $query="select bkid,bkname,bkauth,bkpub,bkedn from books where bkauth=$bkauth";
                            $result=mysql_query($query);
                        }
                        if($bkpub!="" )
                        {
                            $query="select bkid,bkname,bkauth,bkpub,bkedn from books where bkpub=$bkpub";
                            $result=mysql_query($query);
                        }
                        if($bkedn!=""  )
                        {
                            $query="select bkid,bkname,bkauth,bkpub,bkedn from books where bkedn=$bkedn";
                            $result=mysql_query($query);
                        }
                    }
                    echo "<table border='1'>";
                    echo "<th>BOOK ID</th><th>BOOK NAME</th><th>BOOK AUTHOR</th><th>BOOK PUBLISHER</th><th>BOOK EDITION</th>";
                    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))
                    {
                        echo "<tr>";print("<td>{$row[0]}<td>{$row[1]}<td>{$row[2]} <td>{$row[3]}<td>{$row[4]}\n");echo "</tr>";
                    }
                    echo "</table>";
                 }
                 mysql_close($link);
                ?>
    </BODY>
```

Comment: As a beginner, this would be a good time to disregard deprecated methods, e.g. mysql_. See PDO and/or mysqli_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of checking each field just change your query as follows. Use `OR` and `LIKE` in `WHERE` clause

```
$query="select bkid,bkname,bkauth,bkpub,bkedn from books where bkid LIKE '%$bkid%' OR bkname LIKE '%$bkname%' OR bkauth LIKE '%$bkauth%' OR bkpub LIKE '%$bkpub%' OR bkedn LIKE '%$bkedn%' ";
```

**EDIT**

```
$query="select bkid,bkname,bkauth,bkpub,bkedn from books where 1=1 ";
if($bkid!="" ) {

      $query .= " AND bkid=$bkid";
}
if($bkname!="") {

      $query .= " AND bkname=$bkname ";                       
}
if($bkauth!=""  ) {

       $query .= " AND bkauth=$bkauth";
}
if($bkpub!="" ) {

       $query .= " AND bkpub=$bkpub";
}
if($bkedn!=""  ) {

       $query .= " AND bkedn=$bkedn";
}

$result=mysql_query($query);
```

This will append conditions to where clause only if the value not equal to null

Comment: What you're saying that I know but I need to do a single query from any field's data from the form. I need a specific query for either bkid bkname or bkedn so "LIKE" clause doesn't help here

Comment: gives error -> mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\library\querybook.php on line 57

Comment: @phpbeginner, sorry I forgot to add AND . I have edited my answer

Comment: yes that's right I figured it out myself by deleting 1=1 in the query string and using single quotes like bkpub='$bkpub'.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement:

```
if(isset($bkid) || isset($bkname) || isset($bkauth) || isset($bkpub) ||isset($bkedn))
```

would evaluate to true even if all fields had been entered. Try:

```
if(isset($bkid) && isset($bkname) && isset($bkauth) && isset($bkpub) &&isset($bkedn)){
   //insert record
}
elseif(isset($bkid) || isset($bkname) || isset($bkauth) || isset($bkpub) ||isset($bkedn)){
   //select record
}
```

Comment: Please if you could take some part of my code posted in the question and modify it and then post.because i can't understand what you say..i  don't need to insert anything I just need a query formation from the form's data

Comment: I did "take some part of [your] code posted in the question and modify it" But I'm not going to rewrite the whole thing for you (I have work to do).

Comment: There are, in my opinion, a lot of flaws to your code logic. But I also noticed you need to enclose your queries in single quotes: "select bkid,bkname,bkauth,bkpub,bkedn from books where bkauth='$bkauth'" on string data types. The LIKE clause will also help.